# Slide away landing page of website

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8

I have a landing page on my website. 
I want to be able to click or slide it away to view the actual website (sort of like the Windows 8 lock screen)

I have tried to use an onclick event on the landing page to open the website but it does not give the desired effect. I need it to be seamless and fast.

How could I go about doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Position: fixed;` for the landing page content and listen for `click` in JavaScript

as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/5HXaQ/5/

You can use different CSS transition functions to achieve the kind of slide effect you need
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function